# How to display XML parsed data in UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, xcode, uilabel

I am trying to display the data parsed from an XML file from the web to a UILabel called profilesLabel.

I'm trying to display all the lastName's in the label, but the value is set to the email address for some reason. Can someone help me understand why as I'm new to objective-c

here is the code:

```
-(id)loadXMLByURL:(NSString *)urlString
{
    profile = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
    parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:data];
    parser.delegate = self;
    [parser parse];
    return self;
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    currentNodeContent = (NSMutableString *) [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
}


-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"firstname"])
    {
        currentProfile = [ViewController alloc];
        isStatus = YES;
    }

    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"lastname"])
    {
        currentProfile = [ViewController alloc];
        isStatus = YES;
    }

    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"email"])
    {
        currentProfile = [ViewController alloc];
        isStatus = YES;
    }

    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"address"])
    {
        currentProfile = [ViewController alloc];
        isStatus = YES;
    }

}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"firstname"])
    {
        currentProfile->firstName = currentNodeContent;
        NSLog(@"%@",currentProfile->firstName);
    }

    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"lastname"])
    {
        currentProfile->lastName = currentNodeContent;
        NSLog(@"%@",currentProfile->lastName);
        last_Name.text = currentProfile->lastName;
    }

    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"email"])
    {
        currentProfile->lastName = currentNodeContent;
        NSLog(@"%@",currentProfile->lastName);
        last_Name.text = currentProfile->lastName;
    }

    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"address"])
    {
        currentProfile->lastName = currentNodeContent;
        NSLog(@"%@",currentProfile->lastName);
        last_Name.text = currentProfile->lastName;
    }


    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"profiles"])
    {
        [self->profile addObject:currentProfile];
        currentProfile = nil;
        currentNodeContent = nil;
    }
}


- (IBAction)bringFont:(id)sender
{
    //Here is a button that should show the parsed data in profilesLabel when pressed
    profilesLabel.text = currentProfile->lastName; //Shows email address for some reason
    //What I want is to show every single profile in profilesLabel underneath each other       
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [profilesScrolView setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [profilesScrolView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(680, 1200)];


    [super viewDidLoad];
    xmlParser = [[ViewController alloc] loadXMLByURL:@"http://dierenpensionlindehof.nl/XML_File.xml"];

}
```

Any help would be appreciated, Tahnks!

Comment: currentProfile = [ViewController alloc] - maybe you should call some of init methods here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is the issue that here:

```
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"profiles"])
    {
        [self->profile addObject:currentProfile];
        currentProfile = nil;
        currentNodeContent = nil;
    }
```

you are setting `currentProfile` to `nil`

and then using currentProfile here:

```
- (IBAction)bringFont:(id)sender
{
    //Here is a button that should show the parsed data in profilesLabel when pressed
    profilesLabel.text = currentProfile->lastName;
```

**EDIT:**
After clarification that the issue was wanting to know how to display different data.

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{

    ...

    // At the end of each loop add current profile to the mutable array
    [profile addObject:currentProfile];

    // Now you can set currentProfile to nil
    currentProfile = nil;
}


- (IBAction)bringFont:(id)sender
{
    // If you want to display all of this data I would recommend creating a 
    // UITableView and have each entry as a row's title. But thats another 
    // issue so to set them all into the label as you asked:

    // Loop through the array and add the strings together adding a newline each time
    NSMutableString *str = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

    for(NSObject *obj in profile)
    {
        // Obj will need to be casted to whatever type 'currentProfile' is
        [str appendFormat:@"\n %@", obj->lastName];
    }

    // Compute what height the UILabel needs to be to display this string
    CGSize expectedSize = [str sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:[UIFont systemFontSize]] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(320, 9999) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

     CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, expectedSize.width, expectedSize.height);
    [profilesLabel setFrame:newFrame];
    [profilesLabel setText:str];
}
```

**EDIT 2:**

After yet more clarification that the issue is that you don't have the last names, please draw your attention to the fact that you are assigning everything to lastName in this function:

```
if([elementName isEqualToString:@"lastname"])
{
    currentProfile->lastName = currentNodeContent;
    NSLog(@"%@",currentProfile->lastName);
    last_Name.text = currentProfile->lastName;
}

if([elementName isEqualToString:@"email"])
{
    currentProfile->lastName = currentNodeContent;
    NSLog(@"%@",currentProfile->lastName);
    last_Name.text = currentProfile->lastName;
}

if([elementName isEqualToString:@"address"])
{
    currentProfile->lastName = currentNodeContent;
    NSLog(@"%@",currentProfile->lastName);
    last_Name.text = currentProfile->lastName;
}
```

in every section you use:  `currentProfile->lastName = currentNodeContent;`  you need to set the other values inside currentProfile !!!

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply, so what should I do then? Sorry I am new to Objective C.

Comment: when you set something to nil you are removing the data attached to it. Only set it to nil when you are done with it, for example in the viewDidDisappear callback etc.

Comment: try using [profilesLabel setText:currentProfile->lastName]; Instead, if that doesn't work put in an NSlog in this method and confirm that the data is not nil / null at this point. If so you are not saving the data outside the context of the parsing function

Comment: Thanks, but still no luck.. Can you maybe edit the code above so I can see what exactly you meant

Comment: @Amin No i'm not editing your code incase someone else spots an issue. It couldn't be more simple. remove this line 'currentProfile = nil;' altogether, replace this line 'profilesLabel.text = currentProfile->lastName;' with the following two lines 'NSLog(@"Is there any value: %@", currentProfile->lastName); [profilesLabel setText:currentProfile->lastName];'  and then tell me what was printed by that NSLog

Comment: The output is this: Is there any value: a.ziarkash@hotmail.com.. It takes the email address element form the xml file

Comment: Yes it did display the email address in the label, but it used to display that before this editing aswel.. I want to display the lastName for all the profiles (http://dierenpensionlindehof.nl/XML_File.xml) of the XML file one underneath the other

Comment: @Amin 'The parsed data shows correctly in output window using NSLog but for some reason it won't show on the label.'  That is not even remotely the same question, ill edit my answer so .....

Comment: Yes in the output window it shows the names correctly when the app is loaded, but with this button I want to display the same in profilesLabel.. but when I press the button the email address shows on the label and not the name

Comment: @Amin I added 2 edits to my answer. You need to learn to describe your issue in your question. Firstly you described it as though the value was nil, when you just wanted different values. You then described it as though you didn't know how to added all the values into the array. Then finally you revealed that the issue is that the email address is not where you are expecting it to be. Please learn from this mistake as very few others would have stuck around this long. Please upvote and mark my answer as top answer before you leave as I deserve at least that

Comment: Thanks Simon, [str appendFormat:@"\n %@", obj->lastName]; this gives an error saying: NSObject does not have a member named "lastName". And this: [profilesLabel setFrame:expectedSize]; says sending CGSize to parameter of incompatible type CGRect.. I will try to describe the question more precise next time, thanks!

Comment: @Amin I changed the code for the CGSize, I stopped what I was doing when you left that last comment to work on Edit 2 so i didn't test it. As for obj I thought you would have know to cast it, my mistake, I left a comment. Don't forget to mark as top answer as well as upvoting so others will known this solved the issue

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by: Obj will need to be casted to whatever type 'currentProfile' is.. CGRect newFrame gives the error: Expected ")" and when I insert it I get other errors

Comment: @Amin I made a typo in the newFrame function, ive edited it, if you didn't spot that and don't understand what casting is, its sounds like you are very unfamiliar with even basic C programming, I strongly recommend you get a book on c / c++ and another on objective-c. I have no idea what the type of currentProfile is, is it a struct, class etc? I declared the for each loop to search through NSObject's in the loop as I had no other idea what they could be. Referring to "currentProfile"'s as NSObject's losses all of their properties due to the rules of inheritance. Obj will need to be casted

Comment: @Amin as whatever type it is in order to access these properties e.g. ((<classname> *)Obj)->lastName

Comment: Aah ok I understand what you mean now.. it is a ViewController.. it is declared on the top as ViewController *currentProfile; I changed it to for(ViewController *obj in profile).. but still no luck.. Now when I press the button, the profilesLable just disappears..

Comment: @Amin You need to read a book on this subject, a viewController should not be used in such a fashion, it is an object used for creating a screen. There is a huge amount of logic and properties that are going to waste. You need to learn how to define your own classes. Whats more the arrow notation is very rarely used in favour of the inbuilt getters and setters. Once more "Edit 1" was what I thought your question was, when you left that last comment I stopped working on it. The answer to your question is "Edit 2". If you have further difficulties with the UI please post another question